# Jasperreports time series chart

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a csv file as the data source. I want to create a time series chart to show the data during a day. The time series data from csv file is like `0:15  0:30  0:45 ... 23:45`, and every time pot has a value which I want to show in the chart.

So I just use: `new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse($F{time})` to be the Time period expression, but the chart looks like just one dot, and just `23:59:59.999` and `00:00:00.000` on the x-axis

How do I fix it to show `0:15 0:30 0:45 ... 23:45` on x-axis and corresponding value on y-axis? How do I set the time period expression, and any other setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show each entry in your CSV file on the X-axis, don't use the time series charts, but the "Line" chart.
You don't have to parse the date either - simply assign the field to the "Category expression" and you should be done.