# Jasperreports time series chart timePeriod Expression

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have dataset with 00:00:00,00:00:15...
how to set it to be the timePeriod Expression to show one day's time from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59

i put (Date)new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse($F{time}) into the timePeriod Expression
but the chart just show one time point

Comment: Same question answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813866/jasperreports-time-series-chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have gaps you can use Line chart like DeGriz's link to Tarnschaf's answer.

If you may have gaps or would like to summarise the data ensure you use `<timeSeriesDataset`**`timePeriod="Second"`**`>` or perhaps `timePeriod="Minute"` otherwise it tends to default to something large like a year, hence one data point.

> THE JASPERREPORTS ULTIMATE GUIDE: **Time Period Expression**
>
> > This expression returns a java.util.Date value from which the engine will extract the
> >     corresponding time period depending on the value set for the timePeriod attribute
> >     mentioned earlier in the Time Series dataset. For instance, if the chart is about yearly
> >     data, the engine will extract only the year from the date value, or if you are gathering
> >     monthly data, the engine will use only the month value from the date object returned by
> >     this expression.

I think you may also be asking to set the Min and Max for the axis to exactly one day, for this I believe you can use `<domainAxisMinValueExpression>` and `<domainAxisMaxValueExpression>`

Comment: And note iReport has a bug in that it will NOT populate timePeriod you must do it manually, http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport/tracker/view.php?id=5467